# Programmatically erase data of a sqlite database using ormlite library

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'd looking for a method to erase all data of a ormlite database or delete the database (and then recreate it) with ormlite on android.

At this time, I can only change the DATABASE_VERSION of the DatabaseHelper.

But I have to compile the application.

Does someone know a method to handle that case?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I'd looking for a method to erase all data of a ormlite database or delete the database (and then recreate it) with ormlite on android.

@Julia's answer will work well.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) also supports a [`TableUtils.clearTable()` method call](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html#clearTable(com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource,%20java.lang.Class)) which removes all rows from a table:

That won't clear a database but you can clear each table in turn.  Something like the following:

> TableUtils.clearTable(getConnectionSource(), YourClassHere.class);

**Edit:**

@max4ever pointed out that [context.deleteDatabase(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteDatabase%28java.lang.String%29) is a lot faster than other ways of clearing a database.  But this call will remove the table definitions while `TableUtils.clearTable(...)` leaves the schema intact.

Comment: this is painfully slow, takes about 30seconds on 10 tables, context.deleteDatabase is instant

Comment: @Gray `context.deleteDatabase(...)` clear all database data and this is difference with `TableUtils.clearTable` thats right?

Comment: Yes @mahdipishguy.  The delete database call will remove the table definitions.  The clear table just removes all data from the table but leaves the schema intact.

Comment: @Gray clearTable reset A_I ids? reset to start from one

Comment: No idea @mahdipishguy.

Answer (score 5):

You can call

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

in your `DatabaseHelper` class which extends `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`. `context` is passed to the `DatabaseHelper` class in the constructor.

The next time the database is needed, it is recreated and

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource)
```

is called.

Comment: if i use this, then ormLite doesn't see the changes and i have to kill and reopen the app for it to see, is there some way to force ormLite to refresh and see there is no db so it will recreate it ?

Comment: I ran into the same problem: the file has been deleted, but the data was still in memory. I tried `null`ing the DAOs to no avail. I was thinking if maybe calling `close()` would help, but I guess that would mess too much with the sort of reference counting of `OpenHelperManager.getHelper()` and `.releaseHelper()`?

Answer (score 3):

To delete the database use these commands:

```
this.connectionSource.close();
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

To recreate/open the current database use these commands:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, 0, null);
this.connectionSource = new AndroidConnectionSource(db);
```

You will have to keep a reference to the context in your database helper.